# HTML signature showing old image for URL

Tags: html, html-email, signatures

I recently created html email signatures for my office (uses gmail and apple mail). Everything was going well until we found out that sometimes the photo we use loses it's formatting and goes full size.

We have a webpage where we all have 200x200 photos and a description. I took those urls and put them in an 80x80 table cell to size it down for the email signature.

I thought "I'll just change the urls of the 200x200 photos and upload 80x80 versions with the original url so everything will update automatically and I don't have to touch everyone's computer again". The only problem is that that's not happening. We're using Expression Engine as our CMS and even though I delete the original files, without uploading a different photo in it's place, it still shows the full-size photo.

Any ideas on where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Try a different browser? Could be something to do with a browser cache.

Comment: I cleared everything out and tried it on a bunch. I'm not sure there's a cache for apple mail or gmail so I didn't clear that out if there is one though. my thought process is that if it loads the image everytime we compose an email, if the photo changes, the email signature should reflect that....but alas, no.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uploading images with a different file name? It works sometimes. If you are checking in outlook and have images download by default then it is kind of cached and difficult to remove. Renaming the same file and uploading often works.

Also i have noticed some CDN's taking time to show the new image if a file is replaced on the server. Again try and upload with another file name.

Comment: Well the goal for this is for them to have the same filename so I don't have to change the code on everyone's computers. talked with apple support and apparently there are some issues in macOS that cause this :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure Apple Mail doesn't do that, you can use Signature Manager (http://signaturemanager.eu/) - it creates a proper HTML format for the signature so Mail.app can't mess with it.

You could also do it manually, there's plenty of instructions how to create HTML signature on a Mac, but using something like Signature Manager is much easier.